# DotNetOpenAuth: Mock ClaimsResponse

Tags: c#, mocking, dotnetopenauth

I was wondering how I can mock the ClaimseReponse class in DotNetOpenAuth?

This is the class(remove a few properties):

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class ClaimsResponse : ExtensionBase, 
                                     IClientScriptExtensionResponse,
                                     IExtensionMessage, 
                                     IMessageWithEvents, 
                                     IMessage
{
    public static bool operator !=(ClaimsResponse one, ClaimsResponse other);
    public static bool operator ==(ClaimsResponse one, ClaimsResponse other);

    [MessagePart("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [MessagePart("fullname")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj);
    public override int GetHashCode();
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
ClaimsResponse MockCR = new ClaimsResponse();
MockCR.Email = "hello@sayhi.com";
MockCR.FullName = "Mister T";
```

I get the following error: '...ClaimsResponse(string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Kind regards,

Pickels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong answer - correct answer in comments**

You have to create it through a `ClaimsRequest` object:

```
ClaimsRequest request = new ClaimsRequest();
ClaimsResponse response = request.CreateResponse();
```

Comment: When I try that I get the following error:
failed: System.InvalidOperationException : A Simple Registration request can only generate a response on the receiving end.

Comment: Oh, whoops.  Sorry.  You're right.  I guess there's no public way to create a `ClaimsResponse`.  DotNetOpenAuth reserves the exclusive capability of doing that internally.